# How import cplex in google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, cplex, solver, pyomo

!apt install cplex-utils

!pip install cplex

solver = SolverFactory('cplex')

res_NLP= solver.solve(HN_model)

The error is:

> WARNING: Could not locate the 'cplex' executable, which is required
> for solver
> cplex
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ApplicationError                          Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 1 solver = SolverFactory('cplex')
> ----> 2 res_NLP= solver.solve(HN_model)
>
> 2 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyomo/opt/solver/shellcmd.py in
> available(self, exception_flag)
> 123             if exception_flag:
> 124                 msg = "No executable found for solver '%s'"
> --> 125                 raise ApplicationError(msg % self.name)
> 126             return False
> 127         return True
>
> ApplicationError: No executable found for solver 'cplex'

Answer (score 3):

Within IBM Watson Studio, CPLEX comes pre-installed in the Notebooks. But with other Notebook cloud providers, you need to find a way to install it, or else call CPLEX as a service in the IBM Cloud.

You could try to use dowml : https://xavier-nodet.medium.com/submit-decision-optimization-jobs-to-wml-using-dowml-be26e0de6b7f

Or directly wml : https://pypi.org/project/ibm-watson-machine-learning/

With google colab

```
!pip install cplex
!pip install docplex
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)



mdl.export("buses.lp")

!cat buses.lp
```

works fine and gives

```
Requirement already satisfied: cplex in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (20.1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: docplex in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (2.22.213)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from docplex) (1.15.0)
\ This file has been generated by DOcplex
\ ENCODING=ISO-8859-1
\Problem name: buses

Minimize
 obj: 500 nbBus40 + 400 nbBus30
Subject To
 kids: 40 nbBus40 + 30 nbBus30 >= 300

Bounds

Generals
 nbBus40 nbBus30
End
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, `SolverFactory` seems to be a Pyomo class, and require the CPLEX Interactive executable program to be available locally on the machine where the Pyomo code is executed.

Unless you have a way to install arbitrary executable files on the platform you use, which I very highly doubt if you're not using your own computer, you will have to find another way.  Alex's answer proposes two...

Answer (score 0):

When you're working in the colab you need to install `cplex` from `pip`. When you install `cplex` from pip, you need to use the `cplex_direct` interface in `pyomo` in order to avoid such errors, since the `cplex` interface will use the shell approach to solve the problem.

Using Google Colab, this should work

```
!pip install pyomo -q
!pip install cplex -q

import pyomo.environ as pyo

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.s = pyo.Set(initialize=[1,2,3,4,5])
model.x = pyo.Var(model.s, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

model.c = pyo.Constraint(expr=model.x[model.s.last()]>=5)

model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=sum(model.x[s] for s in model.s), sense=pyo.minimize)

solver = pyo.SolverFactory('cplex_direct')
solver.solve(model)
model.x.display()

x : Size=5, Index=s
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      1 :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
      2 :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
      3 :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
      4 :     0 :   0.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
      5 :     0 :   5.0 :  None : False : False : NonNegativeReals
```

I don't use `CPLEX` a lot, therefore, I'm not fully sure, but I think this free approach should have a limit in the number of var, constraints or others