# Can not Deploy Cplex Model as WebApp to cloud (Streamlit Share) using IBM CPLEX Academic Initiative

Tags: python, docker, cplex, docplex, docplexcloud

I have built the Cplex Model for scheduling in Python, here I am using IBM CPLEX Academic Initiative. I have also created simple WebApp (With basic UI of uploading data to feed to the model & getting result) for my model using Streamlit, it works fine on my localhost.

But when I try to deploy it on cloud (Streamlit cloud), it throes me an error for Cplex. (i.e. docplex.cp.utils.CpoException: Executable file 'cpoptimizer' does not exists). I get it that on my machine I have installed the Python API for CPLEX Academic Initiative, but I am wondering how to use that in my webApp on Cloud.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you so much in advance! Hope to hear any solution! :)

Comment: Can you include the executable file in the GitHub repo for your app?

Comment: Hi @CarolineFrasca, I also tried adding executable in the Git repo, but still it's the same. Should I need to add an absolute path to that file in order to make it use the executable? even I'm not sure about it and how to do it! Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it's difficult for us to tell what's going on without looking at any code. Check out the doc on providing a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69844095/how-import-cplex-in-google-colab ?

Comment: Thank you! @AlexFleischer, I am wondering if I can use it with IBM CPLEX Academic Initiative?